# Music Player and Audio Recording Crashes Randomly

Tags: applications, music-player, audio-recording, nova-launcher, crash-reports

My **Music Player** can't play more than **5mins & 10sec** after you stopped using the screen, same with my **Audio Recorder** and after the short records it stores as **.3gpp.tmp** which can't play on android because of the (.tmp). I was told that **Nova Launcher** app can help but I can't get the full details.

**More Details.**

Music Crashes on **Boom player, Google Play music, VLC & Music player by Mobile_V5**.
Yes I withdrew from Battery Optimization and it didn't work.

Model: **Itel A51**

Version: **6.0**

Comment: Looks like you just self-answered your question: your music players get closed by Doze (battery saving feature of Android) – and you can work around that by excluding them from battery optimization.

Comment: Why are you guys confusing me here? I post an issue you ask for more details. I provide necessary details, you close the topic and show option for delete. Now I deleted and create a new one with full details your remembered I have one I created earlier. Be helpful am not always here

Comment: I didn't close your post, and as far as I can see noone showed you an option to delete. The closure of your original post was for lacking sufficient details to be answered; once edited accordingly, such a post can of course be re-opened. Maybe our [tour] can help you understand how SE sites work? // Back to topic: is exempting your music player from optimization not solving your issue? You wrote when you did so they worked – or did I misunderstand that?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the procedures. Anyway "Battery Optimization" didn't work, when I set it not to Optimize. I once saw how to do it with Nova Launcher App but can't pin the site link again.

Comment: Ah, a spelling mistake, I see. I don't know the device, but could it be a resource issue? I tried to look it up, but all I could find was a [Lava A51](https://www.gsmarena.com/lava_a51-8406.php), which seems to match what you wrote. If your device also comes with only 512M RAM, it could be the [LMK](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-management#low-memory_killer) (Low Memory Killer), see e.g. [this question](/q/183401/16575). Could you try to grab some logcat details? Our [logging tag-wiki](/tags/logging/info) should help you with that.

Comment: I am able to find that device, please check it out: https://gadgetstripe.com/itel-a51-specs/